# How to get Query/Mutation operation name

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm new to Spring boot + GraphQL.
I need to get the Query/Mutation operation name inside my controller class.

**Purpose :** Need to grand permission to some users to specific mutation/Query operations.
Here the user type will be passed as a request header and will be validated and check whether the user is allowed to access that operation.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> callGraphQLService(@RequestBody String query, @RequestHeader("user") String userName) {
    ExecutionResult result = graphService.getGraphQL().execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
            .query(query)
            .context(userName)
            .build());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> Suggest any efficient mechanism to perform authorization for specific Query/Mutation

Answer (score 13):

I think you're thinking of authorization in REST terms here, and it doesn't map well to GraphQL. Instead of a single decision at the top level based on the operation name (or based on the URL in REST), you need a more granular approach. You need to know who's allowed to see/do what **at the field level**, as the client is allowed make ad-hoc selections.

There's multiple ways to do this, but since you mentioned Spring, you can simply use Spring Security at the service level. If each protected field is backed by a service method (and it should be), you can protect those methods using Spring Security as usual.

Even better, you should also provide a custom `GraphqlFieldVisibility` implementation, so that unauthorized clients can't even know about the *the existence* of fields they're not allowed to see in the schema. You can use e.g. Spring's `SpelExpressionParser` to make decisions on what parts of the schema are visible dynamically, for each user, based on Spring Security rules.

If Spring Security is not an option, you can implement a custom `Instrumentation` (e.g. by extending `SimpleInstrumentation`). There you can implement the callbacks like `beginExecuteOperation`, that will give you access to the parsed query (enough if you really just want to do REST-style top-level auth only), or `begin(Deferred)Field` (which gives you access to the `FieldDefinition`) or `beginFieldFetch/instrumentDataFetcher` (which gives you access to the entire `DataFetchingEnvironment`) to perform auth per-field.

If you go this way, you can keep the auth information (e.g. the required roles) in the field definition itself as directives. And keep the currently logged in user in the shared context. This way you always have everything you need to do authentication at each level.

In all cases, it's advisable to provide `GraphqlFieldVisibility` to completely hide the existence of the protected fields contextually.

Here's an abstract example showing the major points using the `Instrumentation` approach (as you need nothing special for the Spring Security approach, just use Spring Security as usual):

```
//Checks if the current user has the needed roles for each field
public class AuthInstrumentation extends SimpleInstrumentation {
    @Override
    public DataFetcher<?> instrumentDataFetcher(DataFetcher<?> dataFetcher, InstrumentationFieldFetchParameters parameters) {
        GraphQLFieldDefinition fieldDefinition = parameters.getEnvironment().getFieldDefinition();
        //Each protected field is expected to have a directive called "auth" with an argument called "rolesRequired" that is a list of strings representing the roles
        Optional<GraphQLArgument> rolesRequired = DirectivesUtil.directiveWithArg(fieldDefinition.getDirectives(), "auth", "rolesRequired");
        if (rolesRequired.isPresent()) {
            List<String> roles = (List<String>) rolesRequired.get().getValue();
            User currentUser = parameters.getEnvironment().getContext(); //get the user from context
            if (!currentUser.getRoles().containsAll(roles)) {
                //Replace the normal resolution logic with the one that always returns null (or throws an exception) when the user doesn't have access
                return env -> null;
            }
        }
        return super.instrumentDataFetcher(dataFetcher, parameters);
    }
}
```

You don't have to store the required roles in the directives, it's just a convenient place. You can get the same info from an external source if it's appropriate.

Then register this instrumentation:

```
GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema)
    .instrumentation(new AuthInstrumentation())
    .build();
```

And when executing a query, put the current user into the context:

```
//Get the current user's roles however you normally do
User user = loadUser(userName);
ExecutionInput input = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
    .query(operation)
    .context(user) //put the user into context so the instrumentation can get it
    .build()
```

This way you have everything neatly separated (no auth logic in resolvers, no external context needed) and contextual per field, even without using Spring Security.

Let's go further and make a custom `GraphqlFieldVisibility`:

```
public class RoleBasedVisibility implements GraphqlFieldVisibility {

    private final User currentUser;

    public RoleBasedVisibility(User currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @Override
    public List<GraphQLFieldDefinition> getFieldDefinitions(GraphQLFieldsContainer fieldsContainer) {
        return fieldsContainer.getFieldDefinitions().stream()
                .filter(field -> isFieldAllowed(field, currentUser))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public GraphQLFieldDefinition getFieldDefinition(GraphQLFieldsContainer fieldsContainer, String fieldName) {
        GraphQLFieldDefinition fieldDefinition = fieldsContainer.getFieldDefinition(fieldName);
        return fieldDefinition == null || !isFieldAllowed(fieldDefinition, currentUser) ? null : fieldDefinition;
    }

    private boolean isFieldAllowed(GraphQLDirectiveContainer field, User user) {
        //Same as above, extract this into a common function
        Optional<GraphQLArgument> rolesRequired = DirectivesUtil.directiveWithArg(field.getDirectives(), "auth", "rolesRequired");
        List<String> roles = (List<String>) rolesRequired.get().getValue();
        return currentUser.getRoles().containsAll(roles);
    }
}
```

As you see, visibility depends on the user, which this time you can not get from the context, so you have to instantiate it **per request**. This means you need to **transform the schema and instantiate GraphQL per request** as well. The rest is the same.

```
GraphQLSchema schema = baseSchema.transform(sch ->
        sch.codeRegistry(baseSchema.getCodeRegistry().transform(code ->
                code.fieldVisibility(new RoleBasedVisibility(currentUser)))));

GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema)
        .instrumentation(new AuthInstrumentation())
        .build();
```

With that, you have a full security setup. Unauthorized users won't even know a field exists if they're not allowed to. If they're allowed to see it in general, but they can only fetch it conditionally, the `AuthInstrumentation` covers it.

Comment: Thanks @kaqqao for the reply. Let me try out this.

Comment: In the method RoleBasedVisibility.isFieldAllowed `DirectivesUtil.directiveWithArg(field.getDirectives(), "auth", "rolesRequired");` . How can we protect a field by adding directive with "auth" and "rolesRequired" ?

Comment: Hi Kaqqao, nice solution but it doesn't feel great having to rebuild the schema per request. Have you thought about this some since you answered this?

Comment: @DrSatan1 Unfortunately `GraphQLFieldVisibility` goes onto the schema, so to change it one must transform the schema. The reasoning can be found [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/1488). Do take note that transforming is not rebuilding, and isn't an expensive operation. Still, do remember that if you're using Spring Security, none of this is a concern, as Spring keeps the `SecurityContext` in a `ThreadLocal` which you can get dynamically from `GraphQLFieldVisibility`, so no transformation needed.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't find this answer via https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues/92#issuecomment-414172216, you should know that this is best done via `ResolverInterceptor` now. Thanks @kaqqao! See https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues/92#issuecomment-419661977

Comment: I forgot to say: My previous comment was about the non-Spring Security approach using `AuthInstrumentation`, which is better done through a `ResolverInterceptor` like `AuthInterceptor` now.

Comment: Also, if you're using graphql-java-servlet in front of SPQR, the `AuthInterceptor` can check the roles directly using `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` because the execution context (`context.getResolutionEnvironment().dataFetchingEnvironment.getContext()`) is a `GraphQLServletContext`. Thus there is no need to create a User class - of course this does mean the interceptor will be specific to HTTP servlets.

Comment: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/discussions/2485 @kaqqao If you have a chance to take a look. I would like to handle gracefully the exception. My goal is to create a graphql-rate-limiter based on types